# Set functions as variables to call, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simply put, I am trying to recreate the "button's" functionality called ("On Click ()");
[image]

So that I will be able to put an object, select the one of the scripts from it, and call a function from it. The logic whenever to call it will be handled in the script itself, something like`if(callFunctions) { for(int i = 0; i < functionArray.length(); i++){ functionArray[i].call();}}`
I did try to review the button's script but couldn't recreate this functionality.

Comment: This can be done using reflection and a custom inspector. However, I'd advise against it. Reflection is slow and you probably do not want to use it unless you really have to. You could just use a [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) if that's enough for you?

Comment: Yes, it seems that's the right place to start, but I still don't understand how to ```m_MyEvent.AddListener(function);``` with a **function** from another script, preferably without knowing what the other's script function's name is.

Comment: If you define the variable as UnityEvent type you can assign methods to it as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using UnityEvents. Take a look at this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWxXD-UpvSg

Comment: that was embarrassingly easy, thanks